# django-markdown not showing up in post, but showing up in preview

Tags: django, markdown

I am using django-markdown and I cannot get it to show the actual markdown in my text... I have followed all the instructions and it works in the preview. I am not getting any errors so IDK where to start looking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Django markdown](https://github.com/klen/django_markdown) hasn't been updated since December 2014 and it is quite likely that it isn't compatible with the changes made in django 1.9.

> Requirements
>
> - python >= 2.7
> - **django >= 1.6**
> - markdown

You probably want to use [markdown-deux](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux) or a different library that supports a newer version of django

Comment: ahh ok, forgot to check that, it looked like it was working with 1.9 from the comments on github...

Comment: `>=` means equal or greater than

Comment: @doru - I haven't had my coffee yet, leave me alone!.... thanks though :) (I know from my own experience that this package isn't very useable with 1.9)

Comment: @Sayse I'm having mine now :)